# How to give precedence to a method over a local variable

Tags: ruby

I have a method and a local variable with the same name `x`:

```
class A
  def x; 5 end
end

x = 10
```

I want to refer to the method `x` without using `self.x`. For example, I want:

```
A.new.instance_eval{x} # => 10
```

to return `5`. Is that possible?

Comment: `x` is a *local* variable. [Global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Global+Variables) start with a `$`.

Comment: Oh, I though of a variable assigned in the body of the program was global, didn't know there was an actual global variable modifier

Comment: self.x is probably the cleanest and clearest way to express that you're calling the method. Why do you want to express it differently?

Comment: @KeithBennett I'm using refletion to create the getter in a Context object, I want the getter in the class to appear as a local variable to the block

Comment: @Coirotomas Why would you use reflection when you can use `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor`?  My gut is telling me you're making this way more complex than it needs to be, and complexity is a cost that should be offset by benefit.  Am I wrong? What is the added benefit?  You can also use `Struct`s and `OpenStruct`s for effortless generation of getters/setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in several ways:

```
A.new.instance_eval{x()} # => 5
A.new.instance_eval{send(:x)} # => 5
```

If you only allow `x`, it is impossible. Local variables have lexical scope, and have precedence over method in case of ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was for the OP.  I just moved the comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of telling Ruby that you want a message send instead of a local variable:

1. Variables cannot have arguments: `A.new.instance_eval{ x() }`
2. Variables cannot have a receiver: `A.new.instance_eval{ self.x }`

You could also use reflection:

1. `A.new.instance_eval{ public_send(:x) }`
2. `A.new.instance_eval{ method(:x).() }`

   - since `Method` implements `to_proc`, #2 can also be written as `A.new.instance_eval(&method(:x))`

The cleanest solution would be to rename the local variable.